# Arranging the teams

Tags: combinatorics

Combinatorics puzzle :

Your college is holding the finals of a regional inter‐college sports meet. Teams from four
regional colleges  A, B, C, and D will be arriving in your college soon. It is vacation period
and the hostels are empty, so it is decided that they will be put up in your hostel for the
duration of the meet. Since the rooms are small, and since the rooms are empty because
of the vacation, it is also decided that they will each be allotted a separate room to make
their stay comfortable. Each team has K members.  
As a member of the organizing team, you have been entrusted with allotting them rooms
from a set of 4K side‐by‐side rooms (numbered 101, 102, 103,…(100 + 4K)) in one long
corridor of your hostel. Each room has to be marked as A, B, C, or D, and a team member
of    college X (X = A, B, C, D) will occupy a room marked X.   However, the teams have
requested you for some special considerations for their accommodation. Teams A and B
have both requested that each member of their team should have another member of
their own team in an adjoining room (the room to the left or right). Teams C and D do not
trust each other and have both specifically requested that no member of their team
should be put up in a room with a member of the other team in an adjoining room.
In how many ways can you mark the rooms?
Solution hints:

Number of team members of each (k)=4

Answer: 680

Number of team members of each (k)=7

Answer: 520

I cannot actually come up with a solution.Struggling with it for the past few hours ? Can somebody give me an easy way to solve it.And please suggest me some resources to read up on to master these types of problems.

Source: ICPC problem

Comment: I imagine there is no particularly nice closed-form formula for this quantity, and that the ICPC's intent was to test dynamic programming.

Comment: Yeah,that was actually i'm thinking about.So,form recursion for each team seperately and based on the constraint call it,if possible memoize it and then return the sum.

Comment: @ greg Thanks for your suggestion !